# How do I start a new game in Pokemon Sun/Moon?

Tags: pokemon-sun-moon

In the main menu (After the splash screen), I only see my save game, Mystery Gift, and Live Competition. How do I start a new game?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You first need to delete your existing saved game.

To delete a save game, hold `UP + B + X` in the title screen (the screen with Solgaleo or Lunala). This will also give you the option to re-pick the language setting of the game after you delete your save.

After you delete your save, you will be able to start a new game.

Comment: Do you get a message asking you to confirm your action or should we be super aware of random button mashing on the title screen?

Comment: @PhilD. You get a dialog asking you to confirm if you want to delete your save file.

Comment: That's a very strange way to delete it! Is this noted somewhere in the game?

Comment: This also works in X/Y and ORAS.